# Do epimorphisms map identity to identity?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

Suppose $f:R\rightarrow R'$ is an epimorphism of rings with identity, can we have 
 $f(1_R)=1_{R'}$ ?

I think I should assume that $f(a)=1_{R'}$, but I don't know how to continue. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: Is you question If $f(1_R)=1_{R'}$ has to hold, or if $1_R$ is the only element which maps to $1_{R'}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f:R\rightarrow S$ be an epimorphism between two rings. Then there exist $r\in R$ such that $f\left(r\right)=1$. Thus

$$f(1)=f(1)\cdot 1=f(1)\cdot f(r)=f(1\cdot r)=f(r)=1$$

as required.